# Can't export apk on eclipse, using my old storekey

Tags: android, eclipse, export, keystore

I've updated my app and want to create a new (updated) apk and upload it.

When I try to select "Use an existing key" , nothing appears in the Alias tab.

It's really wierd, and I can't think of why that happends.

Needless to say, that's the right file and I know the password (Is there any way to check if I'm right on both?)

Thanks.

Comment: if the password it's wrong nothing appear on this combo box, so i will bet this is your cause

Answer (score 0):

Use debug key ?

debug key path:/Users/username/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: Can you expand your answer?

Comment: "Use an existing key" no Alias usually you enter error password。  If you just want to export apk you can use default's debug key。